# Accessing at index of for cicle

Tags: python, for-loop, cpu-word

I have this code:

```
for i in words:
    print i
```

that report 'hello' word for 3 times.
Why if:

```
for i in words:
    print i[0]
```

the report is 'h' word for 3 times and not 'hello' word for 1 times? I should report 'hello' for one time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of what your code does:

```
for i in words:
    print i
```

1. Take every element of the list `words` as `i`
2. Print this element

```
for i in words:
    print i[0]
```

1. Take every element of the list `words` as `i`
2. Print the first element of `i` (which happens to be a string, so the first letter is printed)

To make your code print `hello` only once you should do something like `print words[0]` which will print the first element of the list `words`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `words[0]` instead:

```
print words[0]
```

Indexing on Python strings gives you individual characters:

```
>>> 'hello'[0]
'h'
```

but you appear to be looking to index the `words` list instead:

```
>>> ['hello', 'hello', 'hello'][0]
'hello'
```

The `for` loop does the latter, binding each element in `words` to `i` in turn, letting your loop print it. If you only need to print one element, just use `print` directly instead of using a loop.